# Conditional formatting not working in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet and I want to color those rows which have a '0' (zero) in column 'L'. I am using the EXACT same rules as on another sheet(where the conditional formatting is working), but on this sheet it seem to go wrong for unknown reason. See the screenshot...

[image]

Comment: Do not use the absolute reference. Use the relative reference =L3=0. The reference should be just what you are seeing just before the formula bar.

Comment: Try only selecting the L column and Specifying condition as =0

Comment: suggestions did not help. Either ALL got selected or NONE...

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that a conditional format with relative references is always relative to the cell that is the active cell when the format is defined.

If you select A2:Z100 and use the formula `=$L3=0` then each row will evaluate the cell in column L one row BELOW the current row.

That is exactly the offset that your screenshot shows.

So, when you create the conditional format, take note of the current cell and take care to use a formula that relates to the current cell. With A2:Z100 selected, the formula should be

```
=$L2=0
```

When you copy a conditional format from another sheet, you will need to check that these parameters are the same.

Answer (score 0):

looks good and works for me too.

A trick I use when cond. formatting decides to play up is to use an If statement to force a TRUE / FALSE scenario so you could try:

```
=IF($L3=0,TRUE)
```

Make sure you are selecting the whole range that you want the conditional formatting on...

**UPDATE**

Looks like your data is misaligned. Be sure to start the formula row on the same row as the formatting, otherwise the formula will keep the stagger as it goes through the rows.

*EDIT*

Following discussion this was the issue: "The 'Applies to' field is: =$A$2:$L$100", so as the formula was starting at row 3 it was reading the data from the row below it. Correct formula was `=$L2=0`

Comment: @Alex Hmm strange. Are the values in column L truly 0 - What I mean is are they decimal and being rounded up/down... Could they have spaces before them? Take a look at the ones that aren't playing ball as perhaps the data needs tidying.

Comment: The cell content type if 'general' and the formula in the L columns are like: =IF(AND(J4,K4),1,0)

Comment: I tried to use different columns containing TRUE/FALSE values (columns J and K), and when I do so the formatting changes, but also incomprehensible. TRUE rows are not formatted, but other FALSE rows are. It does not make the slightest sense to me!!

Comment: @Alex Hmm strange I'll try to replicate this give me a moment

Comment: when I copy the sheet into another excel instance and repeat it, it works perfectly...

Comment: @Alex Is the data aligned correctly: Are you starting to apply this formatting from the same cell that the formula references? If you have selected rows `2:44` for example are you starting the formula from the second row: `=$L2=0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147431/discussion-between-alex-and-glitch-doctor).